# Web API GET that allows strings in the URI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am missing something basic about ASP.net Web API. I want a method that pulls a string from a GET:

/api/values/some+string+value

I changed the out of the box GET api/values/5 to this:

```
    public string Get([FromUri] string someString)
    {
        return "some return value";
    }
```

but I only get a 404. What am I leaving out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FromUri` is redundant since GETs don't have a body.

But to answer your question, we need to map `someString` to the correct part of the URI (in your case, it's the last element). Without mapping, the client has to name the arguments in the URL. So, for instance, this will work for you right now:

```
http://localhost:53865/api/values?somestring=foo
```

Which is fine and all, but you want this:

```
http://localhost:53865/api/values/foo
```

You might be wondering, "why does the default `Get(int Id)` work and not mine?" Well, let's take a look at the `WebApiConfig` in the `App_Start` folder of the solution.There, you should see something that looks like:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This sets up WebApi's default routing, which is mywebsite.com/api/controller/id. As long as your controllers' actions follow that simple naming convention, everything will work automatically. Now if you are using WebApi 1 (you really shouldn't be for a new project, but you might be based on your comment), you'd need to add a new mapping **before** the default one. Something like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SomeString", "api/{controller}/{someString}");
```

That used to be the only way, but pretty much no one does anymore. Instead, we use the `[Route()]` attribute, which lets us set up routing for each individual action. So if we add a Routing attribute to yours, it'll look like this:

```
[Route("api/values/{someString}")]
public string Get(string someString)
{
    return "some return value";
}
```

And that should fix it for you. :)

Comment: thanks, but I get

'System.Web.Routing.Route' is not an attribute class 

am I missing a using?

Comment: Do you know if you're using WebApi 1 or 2?

Comment: Ah, updated to 2, and it is allowing the Route. Now I am getting: The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Comment: Glad I could help. I was actually just expanding on my answer a bit. Might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you, nice update to your post. I am still stuck somehow. I did upgrade nuget, and verified I am running Web API 2.2. The default ValuesController has only this in it:

        [Route("api/values/{someString}")]
        public string Get(string someString)
        {
            return "some return value";
        }

yet I am getting a 405 navigating to:

http://localhost:50466/api/values/asdf

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: Dunno what to tell you, it should work. Maybe try creating a new project that's WebApi 2 from scratch instead of WebAPI 1 (on the New Project dialog, it's under "Templates -> Visual C# -> Web"). You only get a WebApi 1 project if you choose "Templates -> Visual C# -> Web -> Visual Studio 2012"

EDIT: And make sure your route matches the variable name. Copy and paste my example above where I use the route and then try to go to localhost:0000/api/values/foo in your web browser.